# Interupt boost thread that is already in condition variable wait call

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost

I'm using the [boost interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) to create server and client programs for passing [opencv mat objects](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-) around in shared memory. Each server and client process has two boost threads which are members of a boost::thread_group. One handles command line IO while the other manages data processing. Shared memory access is synchronized using boost::interprocess condition_variables.

Since this program involves shared memory, I need to do some manual cleaning before exiting. My problem is that if the server terminates prematurely, then the processing thread on the client blocks at the `wait()` call since the server is responsible for sending notifications. I need to somehow interrupt the thread stuck at `wait()` to initiate shared memory destruction. I understand that calling `interrupt()` (in my case, `thread_group.interrupt_all()`) on the thread will cause the`boost::thread_interrupted` exception to be thrown upon reaching a *interruption point* (such as `wait()`), which if left unhandled, would allow the shared memory destruction to proceed. However, when I try to interrupt the thread while it is in `wait()`, nothing seems to happen. For instance, this prints nothing to the command line:

```
try {
    shared_mat_header->new_data_condition.wait(lock);
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Thread interrupt occurred\n";
}
```

I am not at all sure, but it seems like the `interrupt()` call needs to occur before the thread enters `wait()` for the exception to be thrown. Is this true? If not, then what is the proper way to interrupt a boost thread that is blocked by a `condition_variable.wait()` call?

Thanks for any insight.

**Edit**
I accepted Chris Desjardins' answer, which does not answer the question directly, but has the intended effect. Here I'm translating his code snippet for use with `boost::interprocess` condition variables, which have slightly different syntax than `boost::thread` condition variables:

```
while (_running) {

    boost::system_time timeout = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1);

    if (shared_mat_header->new_data_condition.timed_wait(lock, timeout)) 
    {
        //process data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to wait with timeouts, then check the return code of the wait call to see if it timed out or not. In fact I have a thread pattern I like to use that resolves this situation (and other common problems with threads in c++).

http://blog.chrisd.info/how-to-run-threads/

The main point for you is to not block infinitely in a thread, so your thread would look like this:

```
while (_running == true)
{
    if (shared_mat_header->new_data_condition.wait_for(lock, boost::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == boost::cv_status::no_timeout)
    {
        // process data
    }
}
```

Then in your destructor you set _running = false; and join the thread(s).

Comment: Thank you, Chris. A variant of this that is acceptable to me, has been added to an edit in my original question. I am still a bit perplexed because switching to the `timed_wait` call, I tried to use the `thread_group.interrupt_all()` call to see if, since the `timed_wait` is being entered and exited automatically every millisecond, I could could get the `boost::thread_interrupted` exception to be thrown. But, still, nothing happens. If you have any thoughts on why the interrupt is not working, that would be great.

Comment: Hmm - I think I figured it out. I'm using `boost::interprocess` condition variables. The interruption points which are referred to [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points) likely only apply to `boost::condition_variable` rather than `boost::interprocess::condition_variable`.

Comment: My thoughts are, just as you say: don't use interprocess communication constructs when all you are doing is multi threading.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "notify function". Keep a pointer to your condition variable and call that instead of interrupting the threads. Interrupting is much more costly than a notify call.

So instead of doing

```
thread_group.interrupt_all()
```

call this instead

```
new_data_condition_pointer->notify_one()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. At least right now, only the server notifies the client. Since the server process has terminated, it can no longer issue a notify call to get the client out of `wait()`. The client thread is stuck in `wait()`, so it cant issue a `notify_one()` call. I guess the idea is to keep the `new_data_condition_pointer` on the second, IO thread, and use that to issue a notify after a server failure?